# IOS play audio from stream

Tags: ios, swift, streaming, nsdata, nsurlsession

I want to implement a player that plays an audio from a certain URL.
But , I don't want to download the whole file and then play it , but to download chunks `URLSession` to download the file iteratively .
I managed to get the data chunks and I converted them to Audio by using 
`AVAudioPlayer(data: NSata)`

and successfully played a chunk .
My question is : how can I play the next chunk (streaming)?? , in a continuous way ???!

Comment: Do you mean you want to play an audio file (mp3,m4a etc...) from remote URL?

Comment: http live streaming ( HLS ) is a way to steam ... once on your device you could use OpenAL to render each clip ... I wrote such a beast for iOS

Comment: @Jad Yes Exactly , but not by the conventional way \

Comment: @ScottStensland , can you help me ?? , Iv'e got prototype , and it needs some little modifications  :D